# Using includes with multiple associations and separate conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, active-record-query

I have the following query in my `Gallery` model:

```
media_items.includes(:photo, :video).rank(:position_in_gallery)
```

My `Gallery` Model has_many `Media Items` which each have either a `Photo` or `Video` association.

So far this works fine. It returns all the `media_items` including their
`photo` or `video` association, ordered by the `position_in_gallery` attribute of the `media_item`.

However I now have a requirement to limit the Photos returned by this query to only those with an attribute of `is_processing` that is `nil`.

Is it possible to make this same query but with a condition on the photos returned equivalent to:

```
.where(photo: 'photo.is_processing IS NULL')
```

Note that all the videos should be returned regardless and do not include an `is_processing` attribute.

I've tried @mudasbwa's suggestion:

```
includes(:photo, :video).where('photos.is_processing IS NULL').rank(:position_in_gallery)
```

but it gets me:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "photos"

Comment: `.where('photos.is_processing IS NULL')`

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks.

Comment: @mudasobwa I'm still looking to include videos in the query though.

Comment: `media_items.includes(:photo, :video).where('photos.is_processing IS NULL').rank(:position_in_gallery)`

Comment: Unfortunately not: `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "photos"`

Comment: your query should be 'joins' instead of 'include'. Please check this query joins(:photo, :video).where('photos.is_processing IS NULL').rank(:position_in_gallery)

Comment: Oh, indeed, `joins`, it’s Friday evening.

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas and @mudasobwa. Got it working with `includes`. See my answer and thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out I was on the right track. I needed to use `references()`:

```
media_items.includes(:photo, :video).where('photos.is_processing IS NULL').references(:photo).rank(:position_in_gallery)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use pure ActiveRecord with no SQL strings:

```
media_items.includes(:photo, :video).where(photos: { is_processing: nil }).rank(:position_in_gallery)
```